# How to understand range of this function?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]> $A,B,E\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$,

> $\DeclareMathOperator{image}{image}\mathcal{B}=\image(B)=\{Bx:x\in\mathbb{R}^n\}$,
>
> We define a function $F:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$,
>   $F(x)=E^{-1}(Ax+\mathcal{B})$

So, is it a set valued function? I am taking a point $x$ and sending it to the set of points for which $Ex\in y(=Ax)+\mathcal{B}$, means $x\mapsto y+\mathcal{B}$ where $E^{-1}(y+\mathcal{B})$ i.e to the pre-image subspace of the subspace $y+\mathcal{B}$ under $E$ right

Comment: $f : U \to V$ means the values of $f$ are in $V$. If there isn't a way to interpret $E^{-1}(Ax + \mathcal{B})$ as an element of $\mathbb{R}^n$, then whoever wrote that formula defining $F$ messed up.

Answer (score 0):

$f$ is just a function that maps vectors from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to vectors from $\mathbb{R}^n$. (Or what function did you ask for?)

One might interpret $Ax + \mathcal{B}$ as $Ax + U = \{ Ax + u \mid u \in U \}$, which is a set of vectors. Not sure what $E$ is, but it has to map a vector from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, otherwise $f$ would not be well defined.

Comment: I have added the source it is from a paper